# How to handle UI5 sap.ui.unified.FileUploader upload() method on the server side?

Tags: javascript, node.js, file-upload, sapui5

I need to upload a file to an external server with UI5 `sap.ui.unified.FileUploader`. By saying "external" I mean that I have a Node.js server and not an SAP.

View:

```xml
<u:FileUploader id="fileUploader" width="80%"
    sameFilenameAllowed="false" buttonText="" fileType="DOCX" sendXHR="true"
    useMultipart="false" placeholder="Choose a DOCX file" style="Emphasized">
</u:FileUploader>
<Button
    text="Upload File"
    press="handleUploadPress"/>
```

Controller:

```js
handleUploadPress: function() {
    let oFileUploader = this.byId("fileUploader");
    let ip = location.host;
    oFileUploader.setUploadUrl(http() + ip + "/documentFileUpload");
    oFileUploader.upload();
},
```

The server side:

```js
app.post("/documentFileUpload", function (req, res) {
    console.log(req);
}),
```

The POST-request reaches the server, but I don't know what exactly `upload()` sends to the server and how to parse it properly then.

Comment: What is the question? FileUploader does not care about your backend. Please check how to handle non-multipart uploads in Node.js

Comment: @matbtt, I'm just trying to figure out what data the ``upload()`` method sends to the server